# New Chatbot - Workplace by Facebook Channel - not supported by Workplace

Tags: botframework, facebook-workplace

New custom integration app created in Workplace using [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#connect-a-bot-to-facebook-using-the-facebook-adapter) is **disabled** by Workplace citing Azure Bot Services is not supported now.

Are new Workplace Channel bots not supported by Azure Bot Framework?
Please confirm.[Response from Workplace team in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdoNx.png)

Comment: Are you using the Azure Bot Service or a custom adapter?